# full screen camera in iOS app.

Tags: iphone, camera

I am currently trying to build a camera app that will help me use iPhone as a webcam. I have it set up nicely, but it is missing one thing. I am trying to get the camera to be full screen and not have bars on the left and right side. Here is the code that I came up with so far. Can anyone help?

picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2)
picker.cameraViewTransform.ty -= -85;

This shows the camera as mostly in the center, but it has black bars on the let and right.

[Image of side bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4iuZ.jpg)

Comment: Is your app in landscape? What camera picker API are you using?

Comment: @IBAction func chooseFromCamera() {
        let picker:UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.sourceType = .camera
        
        picker.isNavigationBarHidden = true;
        picker.showsCameraControls = false;
        
        picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / -2)
        picker.cameraViewTransform.ty -= -85;
        
        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


Thank you for trying to help joe, its much appreciated.

Comment: > The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. (See https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller)
If you're okay with cropping then I think you can use a scaledBy modifier to crop the _viewport_. (See https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform/1455882-scaledby)

Comment: Thank you joe. appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

> The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only.

— See https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller

If you're okay with cropping and you must have landscape then I think you can use a `scaledBy` function to crop the viewport. See https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform/1455882-scaledby